# How to build a UI similar to Pocket for Mac OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, user-interface

I just started Mac OS X programming and I want to build a UI similar to the Pocket Mac Client.
I started with a SourceList, yet it did not work, regarding the table scrolling. Then I found an NSSplitView, yet it looks quite different (see the second screenshot).
 [image: Pocket Screen shot]
I searched through cocoa controls and some other online repositories for a similar ui and could not find some.
Here is my app test (a table in a NSSplitView). It will work, yet looks quite ugly if I add contents ...
Does somebody have an idea on how to gain a similar look to the pocket UI?
 [image: MyAppTest]

Comment: you can start by changing the `style` of the `NSSplitView` to the thin style. you will also need a view based table view.

Answer (score 0):

you can you use this source for putting buttons on title bar:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ansegmentedcontrol

and for the list you should use NSTableView and View Based stye for Content Mode that active by double slow click on table view, for more info:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html